# How to make a connection between javascript and a python file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, python-3.x, electron

I have a python file which makes some predictions on a csv file and displays the output. I don't have any user input data. Now I am trying to display my predictions on an electronJS app by connecting it to a front-end.

My html file looks as below:

```
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="predict" onclick="get_batsmen()">Predict!</button>
```

Here when I press the predict button, my nodeJS file must be called which connects with the python file in the background and show the predictions. Can anyone please explain to me, how to use the 'onclick' method in html.

and my nodeJS file looks as below:

```
function get_batsmen() {
    document.getElementById("predict").value = "Hang on...."
    var python = require("python-shell")
    var path = require("path")

    var options = {
        scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/Users/vivekchowdary/electron-quick-start/engine')
    }

    var batsmen = new python('Batsmen_Prediction.py', options);

    batsmen.on('message', function(message) {
        swal(message);
    }) 
}
```

My expected result is to show the predictions on the browser or on an electronJS application. But when I try to click on the button nothing seems to happen! Can anyone please help me out with this??

Comment: You could use [jQuery.getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), since you're using Bootstrap v3, which requires jQuery.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I didn't get what you were trying to say.

Comment: Node cannot access the browser elements... it's on the server. I'm not sure what you're trying to do it, but you can't use Node like that

Comment: Can you specify if it's an electron app or web app?

Comment: @Mr.Dijkstra, Yes its an electron app.

Comment: Did you check that the function getting called when button gets clicked also, did you make sure that python-shell is working properly?

Comment: @Mr.Dijkstra, No, the function is not getting called and python-shell is working fine.

Comment: Then, instead of adding onclick on html, in JS file get the reference of button using document.getElementById and add click event to it. Then see if the function getting called.

Comment: @Mr.Dijkstra, It isn't working!